# Detecting common file types

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a script that checks all files in my *Downloads* directory against common file types and then tells me how many of the files in that directory aren't either a GIF or a JPG file. I'm familiar with basic Python but this is the first time I've attempted anything like this and I'm looking for a little help or a point in the right direction?

```
file_sigs = {'\xFF\xD8\xFF':('JPEG','jpg'), '\x47\x49\x46':('GIF','gif')}

def readFile():
    filename = r'c:/temp/downloads'  
    fh = open(filename, 'r') 
    file_sig = fh.read(3) 

print '[*] check_sig() File:',filename #, 'Hash Sig:', 
binascii.hexlify(file_sig)
```

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way. I'd suggest os.walk() and the endswith() functions.

Comment: I wanted to rely on looking at the first few bytes of the file to determine the type... Not just the file extension...

Answer (score 2):

Another option, using the *imghdr* library to look at the headers of the files (it will handle the header checking for you), would be something like this (tweak your root path accordingly):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from os.path import join
import imghdr

stats = {'imgs': 0, 'nonimgs': 0}

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/home/user/Downloads'):
    for name in filenames:
        fullPath = os.path.join(dirpath, name)
        fileType = imghdr.what(fullPath)

        if fileType in ('gif', 'jpeg'):
            stats['imgs'] += 1
        else:
            stats['nonimgs'] += 1

        print "File: {0}, type: {1}".format(fullPath, fileType)

print "non images: {0}".format(stats['nonimgs'])
print "images: {0}".format(stats['imgs'])
```

See the [imghdr doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imghdr.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `listdir` to find all the files and  `Counter` to count the totals of each file type and pass in whatever extensions you want to subtract from the total amount of files

```
import os,os.path
from collections import Counter

def find_files(pth,*args):
    c = Counter((os.path.splitext(name)[1][1:] for name in os.listdir(pth) if os.path.isfile(name)))
    total = sum(c.values())
    spec_tot = sum(c.get(arg,0) for arg in args)
    return total - spec_tot
print(find_files(r'c:/temp/downloads' ,'JPEG','jpg','GIF','gif'))
```

Your counter dict will look something like `Counter({'txt': 9, 'py': 3, 'pyc': 3, 'json': 1, 'py~': 1})`.

`total = sum(c.values())` gets the total amount of files.

`spec_tot = sum(c.get(arg,0) for arg in args)` gets the total of each file extensions you pass in as `*args`.

`return total - spec_tot` will give you all the files minus the extensions you want to ignore.